# In CNN network, what is the mathematics behind second convolutional layer output?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am a little confused about the mathematics of solving the output of a second convolutional layer.
I have an output of the first convolutional layer of shape (11,11,64), and now I have a second convolutional layer where kernel specifications are 64 filters with 3x3 size, the stride is 1, and padding is 'same'. When I check the model summary and all, it shows the kernel of the second convolutional layer has a shape (3,3,64,64) but the output shape of the second convolutional layer is (11,11,64). So I am confused here about how to get (11,11,64). I checked the internet, and they say that the convolution will result in a 11x11x1 shape because of stacking, and for 64 images, it will be 11,11,64. So what is the **mathematics** behind getting the shape 11x11x1? I could only understand the shape should result in 11,11,64,64. Please help me to understand since I need to code this algorithm for hardware.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: This is why people should take a ML/NN course before trying to use frameworks like Keras.

Answer (score 0):

You start with 64 images (more precisely, 1 "image" with 64 channels, but we'll stick with 64 images for simplicity), each has a size of 11 * 11:

```
I1 :: 11 * 11
I2 :: 11 * 11
...
I64 :: 11 * 11
```

Then we have the convolution kernel. Assume the kernel shape is 1 * 64 * 11 * 11, then for each input image (again, it should be "channel" technically), there is a corresponding kernel:

```
K1 :: 3 * 3
...
K64 :: 3 * 3
```

Then we calculate convolution between I1 and K1, I2 and K2, ..., I64 and K64. Now it looks like we have sixty-four 11 * 11 results, but actually, we **ADD** them together into a single one: O1 = K1 * I1 + ... + K64 * I64 where * means convolution. That is where the 1 * 11 * 11 comes from.

Finally, since the actual kernel shape is 64 * 64 * 11 * 11, the output has the shape 64 * 11 * 11:

```
O1 = K1_1 * I1 + ... + K64_1 * I64
O2 = K1_2 * I1 + ... + K64_2 * I64
...
O64 = K1_64 * I1 + ... + K64_64 * I64
```

I hope it makes things somewhat clearer. Coincidentally, I am doing some coding on hardware as well, and I was learning those last month.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I still have a few questions. 1) I believe that every image has 64 kernels corresponding to it, and for every image, the kernels are different. Then how are you adding them to get output? 2) In your response K1_1.....K1_64 are 64 kernels corresponding to image 1?

Comment: 1) The "kernel" of the convolution layer is always the same. You "add" them by adding the resulting matrices.
2) Yes, each kernel corresponds to each channel of the image.

Comment: Hi, I have 64 bias values also. In the calculation of K1_1*I1, I should add the bias_1, K2_1*I2 add bias_2 also right?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```py
input_layer2.shape == (11, 11, 64)
kernel_layer2.shape == (3, 3, 64, 64)

input_layer2[:3, :3].shape == (3, 3, 64)
kernel_layer2[:,:,:,0].shape == (3, 3, 64)
```

its only for output_layer2[0, 0]:

```py
for i in range(64):
    output_layer2[0, 0, i] = np.sum(np.dot(input_layer2[:3, :3], kernel_layer2[:,:,:,i]))
```

finaly for all stride:

```py
output_layer2.shape == (11, 11, 64)
```

Comment: Hi, How did you write this step "input_layer2[:3, :3].shape == (3, 3, 64)". Isn't it should be 11 instead of 3?